# Writing in a file - integer

Tags: c

I'm coding a paint-like.
I have to save `unsigned int` in a file to save what the user draws so he can load it (each pixel color is an `unsigned int` with the lib I use). I only can use `write()` to do it.
First thing I need to do, write the width of the drawing in the file.

```
  unsigned int *pixels;
  int FD;
  unsigned int width;

  width = pix->clipable.buffer.width;
  if (!filename) return (1);
  if ((FD = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR)) == (-1)) 
    return (1);
  pixels = pix->pixels;
  write(FD, &width, sizeof(unsigned int));
  return (0);
```

Width is, for example 1020 when I do `printf("%u\n", width)`.
When I open the file created with 'nano filename', it's written `'\374^C^@^@'`.

I really don't get why :/

Comment: How are you reading `width` back in before you `printf("%u\n", width)`? Also, please visit [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That way we can verify and help with your code.

Comment: Nano is a text editor, when you open it with that, it interprets what you wrote as 4 characters (each one byte) when really you wrote one integer (4 bytes). To test this, you either need to write a program to read the file to see if your int is there, or use a hex editor and convert the bytes to an int yourself to check

Comment: Oh I see, so the value may be right. I'm going to read it and printf it to see if it actually works. Thanks. I'll come back tell you. Also David I didnt understand (sorry for my poor english) : how do I read width ? I dont read it, it's set in the pix structure at the moment I create a pixelarray.

Comment: @ritlew It actually works, the value is okay. I really should've known it. Sorry for that poor topic & thanks for the help. Fly safe o7

Comment: Note: Avoid mistakes: rather than `write(FD, &width, sizeof(unsigned int));`, use `write(FD, &width, sizeof width);` and check the return value of `write()`.

Comment: what is wrong with fprintf()?

Comment: @124 Nothing, its just a matter of using low level functions. By using already made function while learning I think you can miss things. But I'm a just a student, so... (for exemple we re-coded all the str* functions, printf, and malloc soon. of course it is less optimized than the original ones, but its good exercise). And ty for advice chux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nano is a text editor, when you open it with that, it interprets what you wrote as 4 characters (each one byte) when really you wrote one integer (4 bytes). To test this, you either need to write a program to read the file to see if your int is there, or use a hex editor and convert the bytes to an int yourself to check.

Comment: Yeah I wrote a program to read and display value, and it is correct. Thanks for you time.